# "Your SDK doesn't seem to have updated correctly. Please try again." Even after update is done

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle, sdk

[image]

I have an Android app using Facebook SDK, when I try to add new events I get this message "Your SDK doesn't seem to have updated correctly. Please try again."

I  have the latest versions for every package I use (also tried the suggestions shown in the image above)

My *Build.gradle :app* file:

```
   implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:16.3.0")
    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-common:16.3.0")
    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-core:16.3.0")
    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-login:16.3.0")
    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-messenger:16.3.0")
    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-share:16.3.0")
    implementation ("com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:7.0.1")
```

Also, events are being logged with no issues:

[image]

What I did:

1. I updated every implementation to the latest version available (Android & Facebook)
2. I re-synced the build.gradle file and ran the app again.

The error message: *"Your SDK doesn't seem to have updated correctly. Please try again"* should disappear allowing me continue.

Is there anything I'd be missing?